# unix - sed replace file of file with error undefined label

Tags: unix, sed

I'd like to replace the entire line

TEMPLATE_FILE = file.tpl with
TEMPLATE_FILE = tester.sh

I have a file called file.config

```
test0
TEMPLATE_FILE = file.tpl
test1
test2
OUTPUT_DIR = out
```

I would like the replace

TEMPLATE_FILE = file.tpl to TEMPLATE_FILE = tester.sh

OUTPUT_DIR = out to  OUTPUT_DIR = in

```
sed -i 's/(OUTPUT_DIR).*/(OUTPUT_DIR = in)/g' file.config
```

I get this error

```
sed: 1: "file.config": undefined label 'pc.config'
```

The end result would be

```
test0
TEMPLATE_FILE = tester.sh
test1
test2
OUTPUT_DIR = in
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

sed -i -E "s/(TEMPLATE_FILE = file.tpl)/TEMPLATE_FILE = tester.sh/" bpc2.config

Answer (score 0):

Judging from the error message, you may using MacOS. Then the `-i` option requires a string as an argument. Would you please try:

```
sed -E -i '' 's/(TEMPLATE_FILE).*/\1 = tester.sh/g; s/(OUTPUT_DIR).*/\1 = in/g' file.config
```